# WebAPI: Accessing Child Container as a Service Locator

Tags: asp.net-web-api, unity-container, ioc-container, service-locator

In normal ASP.MVC projects we configure the dependency resolver with Unity and the Unity.Mvc3 package from http://unitymvc3.codeplex.com/

We have this test service registered with a [HierarchicalLifetimeManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.hierarchicallifetimemanager%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)

```
container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

And we hook up the container with Mvc in Global.asax.cs:

```
System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Unity.Mvc3.UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

And we run this test controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITestService _service;
    public TestController(ITestService service)
    {
        this._service = service;
    }
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        var locatedService = System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ITestService>();
        if (_service == locatedService)
            return View("Success - Same Service");//This is always the result in an MVC controller
        else
            throw new Exception("Failure - Different Service Located");//This is never the result in an MVC controller
    }
}
```

However, on this project we are adding a number of WebAPI controllers.

We have this configuration in global.asax.cs (using http://unitywebapi.codeplex.com/ for now.  But I am open to suggestions):

```
System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
```

We have created an `ApiTestController` similar to `TestController` inheriting from `ApiController` rather than from `Controller`.
However, the ApiTestController fails its test.  I understand that the `System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver` class and the `System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current` property are specific to Mvc.  But does WebAPI have an equivalent?

`System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService` does not work because the `System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver` instance is the parent container that I configured.  It is not the child controller that was used to inject the ITestService into the constructor.

This user seems to have a similar problem: http://unitywebapi.codeplex.com/discussions/359413
But I feel that this probably has more to do with ASP.NET's WebAPI than it has to do with Unity.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After looking over the source of http://unitymvc3.codeplex.com/ and http://unitywebapi.codeplex.com/ I created this class:

```
public class MyUnityDependencyResolver : Unity.Mvc3.UnityDependencyResolver, System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver
{
    public MyUnityDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer container)
        : base(container)
    {
    }

    public System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Unity.Mvc3.UnityDependencyResolver.DisposeOfChildContainer();
    }
}
```

Configuration in gobal.asax.cs:

```
var myResolver = new MyUnityDependencyResolver(container);
System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(myResolver);
System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = myResolver;
```

`Unity.Mvc3.UnityDependencyResolver` uses `HttpContext.Current.Items` to manage child containers.  `MyUnityDependencyResolver` may not be the most "correct" implementation of `System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver`, but it seems to work so far.

I will mark this as the answer in a couple days if no one else has any better answers.

Comment: this looks as though it will not create child requests at all and therefore, using HierarchicalLifetimeManager will not result in a per request lifetime, but a singleton - so the dependency will be around for the lifetime of the app which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, when you call the GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService, it completely ignores any scope and resolves using the outer non-child container which is around for the lifetime of the application. This is an issue with Web Api and makes it impossible to use constructor injection for per-request dependencies outside of controllers. Confusingly this is completely different behaviour from MVC as you say.

What you can do is use the GetDependencyScope() extension method off HttpRequestMessage. Anything you resolve using this will be in per request scope when using HierarchicalLifetimeManager in conjunction with Unity.WebApi. The request is available from action filters and handlers so may be a viable workaround.

Obviously this is pure service location rather than dependency injection which is far from ideal but I have not found another way to access per-request dependencies outside of controllers.

See [this post](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/11/asp-net-web-api-and-dependencies-in-request-scope/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The `DependencyResolver` is not the right seam for dependency injection in ASP.NET WebAPI.

Mark Seemann has two really good posts on DI with WebAPI.

[Dependency Injection and Lifetime Management with ASP.NET Web API](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/09/28/DependencyInjectionAndLifetimeManagementWithASPNETWebAPI.aspx)

[Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Web API with Castle Windsor](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/10/03/DependencyInjectionInASPNETWebAPIWithCastleWindsor.aspx)

If you want to do it right you should have a look at them.

Comment: He's not using the resolver in his code, only in the infrastructure. And that's to create a UoW nonetheless. You gotta bind to a singleton at some point. This argument is valid only he's using the resolver in the controllers instead of DI-ing the dependencies. Again depending on context, if there's already a service layer with stricter adherence to DI, this too might be OK.